# AngularJS - data binding to class do not work

Tags: angularjs

I would like that "projectMethod.icon" could be binded in the class="{{projectMethod.icon}}" in the following code:

```
 <div ng-model="projectMethods" ng-repeat= 'projectMethod in projectMethods'>

      <i class="{{projectMethod.icon}}"></i> {{projectMethod.icon}} {{projectMethod.file_name}}

 </div>
```

The problem is that if I put it out of the "i" tag, it binds it. But it doesn't when in the class. 
Any idea?

If It was not clear please tell me, thank you!

Comment: Remove the double brackets: To understand why, take a look at this: http://www.thinkingincrowd.me/blog/2013/01/30/string-interpolation-should-not-be-used-with-class-directive-in-angularjs/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ng-class="projectMethod.icon"` to bind class values. Also `ng-model` should not be used in `div` tag.

Comment: thank you, I put also ng-class...why ng-model not in div tag?

Comment: @Colet http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngModel , basically ng-model is for monitoring the value of a input element.